# How to access a generic SD card?

Tags: sd-card

What's the systematic way of accessing an SD card? I've installed one in my reader, but nothing seems to progress.
The end of `dmesg` gives:

```
[ 6647.300380] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, aborting
[ 6647.300392] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 2952
[ 6647.300404] Buffer I/O error on device mmcblk0p1, logical block 113
[ 6647.300576] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 6647.300585] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 6647.300592] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, aborting
[ 6647.300600] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 2560
[ 6647.300608] Buffer I/O error on device mmcblk0p1, logical block 64
[ 6647.300656] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 6647.300664] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 6647.300671] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, aborting
[ 6647.300680] Buffer I/O error on device mmcblk0p1, logical block 64
[ 6647.300761] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 6647.300770] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, retrying
[ 6647.300777] mmcblk0: error -123 sending status command, aborting
[ 6647.300786] Buffer I/O error on device mmcblk0p1, logical block 4
[ 6647.348095] tifm_core: MMC/SD card detected in socket 0:0
```

None of that tells me what the dev might be.
`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82855PM Processor to I/O Controller (rev 21)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82855PM Processor to AGP Controller (rev 21)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-M) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 83)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 03)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) IDE Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.5 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Modem: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Modem Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV280/M9+ [Mobility Radeon 9200 AGP] (rev 01)
02:00.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCI7420 CardBus Controller
02:00.2 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments PCI7x20 1394a-2000 OHCI Two-Port PHY/Link-Layer Controller
02:00.3 Mass storage controller: Texas Instruments PCI7420/7620 SD/MS-Pro Controller
02:02.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection (rev 05)
02:06.0 Ethernet controller: 3Com Corporation 3c905C-TX/TX-M [Tornado] (rev 78)
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

And `sudo fdisk -l` just shows the hard drive.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.3.

Answer (score 2):

Your dmesg output is full of errors. That SD card seems like it's quite faulty. That's why it isn't being made accessible to you.

Comment: It's a while ago now, but I'm pretty sure that card didn't have any trouble in other readers.